# Windows 8.1 Blue Screen Clearing Temporary Files with Disk Cleanup

Tags: windows-8.1, bsod, temporary-files, disk-cleanup

Every time I run Disk Cleanup as an admin (therefore deleting system files) and check the Temporary Files box it finishes fine but when I restart the computer it blue screens says **Boot critical file is corrupt**. When I look at the log file it says `intelide.sys` is corrupted.

One time I went into the recovery partition, found a copy of the file and replaced the corrupted version. At that point the log said another file was corrupted. Let me know if it will help for me to go through the process again and get more exact info.

I believe the issue is caused by one ore more Windows or Microsoft Updates because this did not use to be a problem. Another note is that I have the 'Give me updates for other Microsoft product when I update Windows' setting enabled.

This Windows 8.1 instance in question is a virtual machine so I can create a snapshot before recreating the issue if that helps any troubleshooting steps.

Any idea what is going on or how I can figure out how to fix it?

Really appreciate any help!

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @Ramhound Last paragraph: **Any idea what is going on or how I can figure out how to fix it?** I will edit my post.